# Sofware Installation hangs with graphical interface

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, software-center, apturl

I have a newly installed computer on Ubuntu 16.04.
I have some issue on installing softwares : it does not work when I use a graphical interface such as Software Installation Center or apturl. I have also try to install a specific software that uses an graphical interface to register some user key (Blast2GO) and it didn't work either.
The installation hangs (it seems to block for downloading packages or when trying to establish some internet connections).

When I install softwares using command lines (sudo apt-get install or dpkg), it all works very well. This is quite disturbing. I suppose all 3 problems are related, but can't find any clue of how to solve it. I first thought of proxy connection but while setting the proxy for the whole system in system parameters, it didn't change anything.

Any ideas ?

Thank you for your replies

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Muon Package Manager as GUI package management application. 
You can install it with `sudo apt-get install muon`.

For installing single deb-package you can use Gdebi. You can install it with `sudo apt-get install gdebi`. So if you have deb-package, you can navigate to it with file-manager, then right-click it, then select *Open with GDebi Package Installer* for installation.

Software center seems to be obsolete as Synaptic. You can see the [discussion on mailing-list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2017-August/005156.html) about software installation problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the informations provided, I didn't know muon.
However, the problem was else since it concerned connections through internet to settle packages, muon included.

I have found a solution. To have just configurated the proxy for all system wasn't enough. I needed also to create the file */etc/apt/apt.conf* and add the lines above:

```
  Acquire::http::proxy "http://HOST:PORT_NUMBER/";
  Acquire::https::proxy "http://HOST:PORT_NUMBER/";
  Acquire::ftp::proxy "http://HOST:PORT_NUMBER/";
```

After restarting the system, it worked all fine.